# Adding Google Tag Manager to Android app

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement the Google Tag Manager for Android App by following [tag-manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/).

I get this error:

> Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled

I searched existing questions, some of them said to include `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0` but my app already has the following dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.0'
```